# Spring boot Ignoring Class-Path entry

Tags: spring-boot

I am kind a new to spring and I was building this small application but everytime I run my applilcation I get this

[image]

my application is working fine without any errors but it looks kind of scary and I know it's bad because of the red color. I searched for "Ignoring Class-Path entry" but got completely different stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application is working, you should be able to remove these classpath dependencies from the Manifest.

Spring Boot scans through the Classpath jars' Manifests and checks if any Class-Path entries have a resolvable jar file classpath, and then logs the errors.

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-devtools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/ChangeableUrls.java#L150